# How to combine/match list with specific key/values as hostvar

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible, ansible-facts

I have a question about dicts and lists.

What I want to achieve is, have the key and value from a seperate list saved as fact/hostvar for each matching host.

I'm getting a list from a Confluence API that looks like this (abbreviated):

```json
[
    {
        "title": "MACHINE1",
        "_links": {
            "tinyui": "/x/1234"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "MACHINE2",
        "_links": {
            "tinyui": "/x/5678"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "MACHINE3",
        "_links": {
            "tinyui": "/x/9876"
        }
    }
]
```

What worked to get each individual item (just to debug, and show that the loop itself works) is:

```yaml
- name: DEBUG specific item in list of get_children.json.results
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.title }} {{ item._links.tinyui }}"
  loop:
    "{{ get_children.json.results }}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Ansible Output (here: output for only one machine):

```yaml
"msg": "MACHINE1 /x/1234"
```

Machine Hostnames:

Yes, they are lowercase in my inventory, and in the above list output they are uppercase. But I guess a simple `item.title|lower` would do fine.

```
machine1
machine2
machine3
```

How can I now match the `item.title` with `ansible_hostname` and save above API Output as a fact for **each** machine?

And for clarification: `item.title|lower == ansible_hostname`

I hope it gets clear to what I want to achieve and thanks to everyone in advance :)

EDIT: Thanks to both answers I managed to get it to work. Using `'(?i)^'+VAR+'$'` and some other conditional checks you guys posted definitely helped. :)

Comment: Side note after my answer: delegating a debug task to localhost or any other host is absolutely useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, given the `inventories/tinyui/main.yml` inventory:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    machine1:
    machine2:
    machine3:
    i.do.not.exist:
```

The folowing `tinyui.yml` playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # In real life, this is returned by your API call
    get_children:
      json:
        results: [
          {
            "title": "MACHINE1",
            "_links": {
              "tinyui": "/x/1234"
            }
          },
          {
            "title": "MACHINE2",
            "_links": {
              "tinyui": "/x/5678"
            }
          },
          {
            "title": "MACHINE3",
            "_links": {
              "tinyui": "/x/9876"
            }
          }
        ]
    
    # This won't be defined before you call the API which
    # returns and registers the correct result. If there is
    # no match for host in the returned json, '!no uri!' will
    # be returned below. Adapt with a default uri if needed
    tinyui: "{{ get_children.json.results 
      | selectattr('title', '==', inventory_hostname | upper)
      | map(attribute='_links.tinyui') 
      | default(['!no uri!'], true) | first }}"

  tasks:
    # In real life, you would have called your API
    # and registered the result in `get_children` e.g.
    # - name: get info from confluence
    #   uri:
    #     url: <confluence api endpoint url>
    #     <more parameters here>
    #   run_once: true
    #   delegate_to: localhost
    #   register: get_children
 
    - name: Display tinyui for host
      debug:
        msg: "tinyui for host {{ inventory_hostname }} is {{ tinyui }}"
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/tinyui/ tinyui.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Display tinyui for host] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [machine1] => {
    "msg": "tinyui for host machine1 is /x/1234"
}
ok: [machine2] => {
    "msg": "tinyui for host machine2 is /x/5678"
}
ok: [machine3] => {
    "msg": "tinyui for host machine3 is /x/9876"
}
ok: [i.do.not.exist] => {
    "msg": "tinyui for host i.do.not.exist is !no uri!"
}


PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
i.do.not.exist             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
machine1                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
machine2                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
machine3                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm! Gotta look into selectattr and map again. Definitely learned something new today :)

Comment: Just edited to make sure it does not fail if hostname is absent from result. You still have to call the api prior to using the var else you get an (expected) error.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list of dictionaries by title, taking out the right dict.

You can do this with the following line:

```
"{{ hostsdata | selectattr('title', 'match', '(?i)^'+host+'$') | first }}"
```

- With `selectattr` you filter your list of dicts by the title, where this must match `'(?i)^'+host+'$'`.
  The `(?i)` is the ignore case inline flag for [pattern matching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), concatenated with the hostname (case does not matter because of ignore case flag). `^...$` specifies that the whole string must match, from start to end.
- Since `selectattr` returns a list as result, you can use `first` to take out the first element of the list.

Instead of using `(?i)` you can also set the `ignorecase` parameter, which will look like this:

```
"{{ hostsdata | selectattr('title', 'match', '^'+host+'$', 'ignorecase=true') | first }}"
```

Both variants work equivalently.

---

Entire playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    hostsdata:
      - {
            "title": "MACHINE1",
            "_links": {
                "tinyui": "/x/1234"
            }
        }
      - {
            "title": "MACHINE2",
            "_links": {
                "tinyui": "/x/5678"
            }
        }
      - {
            "title": "MACHINE3",
            "_links": {
                "tinyui": "/x/9876"
            }
        }

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: hostsdata

    - name: Pick out host specific dict
      set_fact:
        machine_data: "{{ hostsdata | selectattr('title', 'match', '(?i)'+host) | first }}"
      vars:
        host: machine3

    - debug:
        var: machine_data

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ machine_data.title }} {{ machine_data._links.tinyui }}"
```

Resulting output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostsdata": [
        {
            "_links": {
                "tinyui": "/x/1234"
            },
            "title": "MACHINE1"
        },
        {
            "_links": {
                "tinyui": "/x/5678"
            },
            "title": "MACHINE2"
        },
        {
            "_links": {
                "tinyui": "/x/9876"
            },
            "title": "MACHINE3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Pick out host specific dict] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "machine_data": {
        "_links": {
            "tinyui": "/x/9876"
        },
        "title": "MACHINE3"
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "MACHINE3 /x/9876"
}
```

To filter multiple machines, here is another example:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ md.title }} {{ md._links.tinyui }}"
  when: md | length
  vars:
    md: "{{ hostsdata | selectattr('title', 'match', '(?i)^'+item+'$') | first | default('') }}"
  with_items:
    - MachINE1
    - MACHINE2
    - machine3
    - unknown
```

Add a `default('')` and a `when:` to skip a non-existent hostname.

Output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=MachINE1) => {
    "msg": "MACHINE1 /x/1234"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=MACHINE2) => {
    "msg": "MACHINE2 /x/5678"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=machine3) => {
    "msg": "MACHINE3 /x/9876"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item=unknown)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the titles to lowercase

```yaml
titles: "{{ get_children.json.results|
            map(attribute='title')|
            map('lower')|
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'title')|
            list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
titles:
  - title: machine1
  - title: machine2
  - title: machine3
```

Replace the lowercase titles and create a dictionary

```yaml
title_links: "{{ get_children.json.results|
                 zip(titles)|
                 map('combine')|
                 items2dict(key_name='title', value_name='_links') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
title_links:
  machine1:
    tinyui: /x/1234
  machine2:
    tinyui: /x/5678
  machine3:
    tinyui: /x/9876
```

Put these declarations, for example, into the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/title_links.yml 
titles: "{{ get_children.json.results|
            map(attribute='title')|
            map('lower')|
            map('community.general.dict_kv', 'title')|
            list }}"
title_links: "{{ get_children.json.results|
                 zip(titles)|
                 map('combine')|
                 items2dict(key_name='title', value_name='_links') }}"
```

Now, you can use the dictionary. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
10.1.0.11 ansible_hostname=machine1
10.1.0.12 ansible_hostname=machine2
10.1.0.13 ansible_hostname=machine3
```

the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    get_children:
      json:
        results:
          - _links: {tinyui: /x/1234}
            title: MACHINE1
          - _links: {tinyui: /x/5678}
            title: MACHINE2
          - _links: {tinyui: /x/9876}
            title: MACHINE3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "My links: {{ title_links[ansible_hostname] }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************
ok: [10.1.0.11] => 
  msg: 'My links: {''tinyui'': ''/x/1234''}'
ok: [10.1.0.12] => 
  msg: 'My links: {''tinyui'': ''/x/5678''}'
ok: [10.1.0.13] => 
  msg: 'My links: {''tinyui'': ''/x/9876''}'
```